# Store lines from a text file in a list of strings

Tags: c++, string, list, file, text

I've been trying to store the lines of a text file in a list in C++. Better, I've been trying to store each word of each line of the text file in a string that is part of a list of strings, but it seems that I'm doing it in the wrong way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  FILE *f= fopen("teste.txt", "r");
  size_t len= 100; // valor arbitrário
  char *line= (char*)malloc(len);
  std::list<string> mylist;   


if (!f)
  {
    perror("teste.txt");
    exit(1);
  }
  while (getline(&line, &len, f) > 0)
  {    //THE REAL PROBLEM
  for (std::list<string>::iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); it++){
    *it=line;     
    cout << *it << '\n';
}
  }
  if (line)
    free(line);
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

The exact problem is that this doesn't give any result. It compiles but nothing results from this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the exact problem is...? Compiler errors, strange behaviour...? And why `*for` :o

Comment: @deviantfan _'And the exact problem is...?'_ It doesn't [compile](http://ideone.com/5ytDea), even not when fixing the `*for`.

Comment: Line 27 is another strange star

Comment: I changed that but it ain't get better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your while loop as follows:

```
  while (getline(&line, &len, f) > 0)
  {
      mylist.push_back(line);     
      cout << mylist.back() << '\n';
  }
```

You cannot access any non initialized items from a `std::list<>`.

Also **NOTE** you should make `line` a `std::string`, and omit the `malloc()` / `free()` calls from your code.

**2nd NOTE:** Use `std::ifstream` instead of `FILE*` for an input file stream.

Here's the fully fixed (no more errors/exceptions on [ideone](http://ideone.com/5ytDea)) code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <exception>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  try
  {
    std::ifstream f("teste.txt");

    if(!f)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open 'teste.txt'!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string line;
    std::list<std::string> mylist;   

    while (std::getline(f,line))
    {
        mylist.push_back(line);     
        std::cout << mylist.back() << std::endl;
    }
  }
  catch(const std::exception& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: '" << ex.what() << "'!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Many thks to your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign a `char*` value to `std::string` by using '=' operator.

Change

`*it=line`   to

`it->assign(line,line+strlen(line);`